# Non-unicode XML representation

Tags: xml, string, unicode, character

I have xml where some of the element values are unicode characters. Is it possible to represent this in an ANSI encoding?

E.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
<value>受</value>
</xml>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xml>
<value>&#27544;</value>
</xml>
```

I deserialize the XML and then attempt to serialize it using XmlTextWriter specifying the Default encoding (Default is Windows-1252). All the unicode characters end up as question marks. I'm using VS 2008,  C# 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I tested it with the following code:

```
 string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><xml><value>受</value></xml>";

 XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.Default };
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(ms, settings))
      XElement.Parse(xml).WriteTo(writer);

 string value = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

And it correctly escaped the unicode character thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?><xml><value>&#x53D7;</value></xml>
```

I must be doing something wrong somewhere else. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question, then yes. You just need a `;` after the `27544`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<xml>
<value>&#27544;</value>
</xml>
```

Or are you wondering how to generate this XML programmatically? If so, what language/environment are you working in?

Comment: Was a typo on my part. Corrected the example.