# Escape text for HTML

Tags: c#, html, escaping

How do i escape text for html use in C#? I want to do

```
sample="<span>blah<span>"
```

and have

```
<span>blah<span>
```

show up as plain text instead of blah only with the tags part of the html :(.
Using C# not ASP

Answer (score 191):

```
using System.Web;

var encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);
```

Comment: If you also want to encode unicode characters to non-unicode, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82008/non-unicode-xml-representation

Comment: Something that you don't want to find out the bad way: The above method by itself does not escape control characters. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4501246/1543677 and use both.

Comment: HttpUtility does not exist anymore (win store apps)

Answer (score 91):

Also, you can use this if you don't want to use the `System.Web` assembly:

```
var encoded = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(unencoded)
```

Per [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx), the difference between `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape()` and `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` is that the former also encodes apostrophe `(')` characters.

Comment: Not to say `SecurityElement.Escape()` escapes for *XML* which is not exactly HTML.

Comment: System.Security.SecurityElement does not exist in windows store apps

Comment: Note that System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape does not remove or escape character 31, which hit us once from an extract of active directory data

Answer (score 61):

If you're using .NET 4 or above and you don't want to reference `System.Web`, you can use [`WebUtility.HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx) from `System`

```
var encoded = WebUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded);
```

This has the same effect as `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and should be preferred over `System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape`.

Comment: Why should it be preferred over SecurityElement.Escape? Are there vulnerabilities in the latter, or is the former just more capable?

Comment: @Travis There are no vulnerabilities in either, it's just that `SecurityElement.Escape` operates on XML and `HtmlEncode` operates on HTML, and XML and HTML encoding have slightly different requirements (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2083770/175157) for details). So, for example, `SecurityElement.Escape` is allowed to use `&apos;`, while `HtmlEncode` is not.

Comment: @Travis I think the even better "excuse" is that **System.Net is available to Portable Class Libraries** and the other two options aren't/don't seem to be this morning. ;^)

Answer (score 19):

In ASP.NET 4.0 there's new syntax to do this. Instead of

```
<%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(unencoded) %>
```

you can simply do

```
<%: unencoded %>
```

Read more here:

*[New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)*

Comment: please give a syntax for Razor? @Nacht

Answer (score 6):

.NET 4.0 and above:

```
using System.Web.Security.AntiXss;
//...
var encoded = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode("input", useNamedEntities: true);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use actual html tags `<xmp>` and `</xmp>` to output the string as is to show all of the tags in between the xmp tags.

Or you can also use on the server `Server.UrlEncode` or `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.

Comment: I made the question more clear. I dont want the tags to be part of html as the user can do </pre> and break it.

Comment: `<xmp>` has been deprecated long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307846/why-was-the-xmp-html-tag-deprecated use `<pre>` instead

Answer (score 2):

For a simple way to do this in Razor pages, use the following:

In .cshtml:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.Encode("<span>blah<span>"))
```

In .cshtml.cs:

```
string rawHtml = Html.Raw(Html.Encode("<span>blah<span>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("Hello, this is Satan's Site")
```

It was the only thing that worked (ASP.NET 4.0+) when dealing with HTML like this. The`&apos;` gets rendered as `'` (using *htmldecode*) in the HTML content, causing it to fail:

```
<a href="article.aspx?id=268" onclick="tabs.open('modules/xxx/id/268', 'It&apos;s Allstars'); return false;">It's Allstars</a>
```

Comment: Re *"htmlencode"*: Do you mean *"HtmlEncode"*?

Answer (score 1):

There are some special quotes characters which are not removed by HtmlEncode and will not be displayed in Edge or Internet Explorer correctly, like `”` and `“`. You can extend replacing these characters with something like the below function.

```
private string RemoveJunkChars(string input)
{
    return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input.Replace("”", "\"").Replace("“", "\""));
}
```

Comment: You are probably serving content using the wrong encoding. IE and Edge have no problems displaying such characters.