# how to show message with angle brackets using telerik radAlert

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

In Grid View when clicked on a row I need to show a message Using RadAlert (telerik)controls, the popup  message contains angle brackets in them like `"this is <swathi> "`. But messsage is being showed as `"this is       "` The string within including angle brackets are missing.

Can anyone give clue how to show pop up message including angle brackets

Comment: Ever heard about HTML tags? I think what you use tries to parse your string... If that is the case, replace the `<` characters with the string `&lt;` and `>` characters with `&gt;`

Comment: yes, it worked, Thanks. can you write this as answer so that I can vote this as Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think RadAlert tries to parse your string as a HTML string...

If that is the case, replace the < characters with the string < and > characters with >

Also, you might face other issues too, so you should escape other characters too: [this question has good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162535/how-do-i-escape-html-characters-in-net-ampquot)

Quoting the accepted answer:

> You can use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` and `HtmlDecode()` for these purposes

Answer (score 1):

You can use html encoding and decoding.

```
 Server.HtmlEncode("");
 Server.HtmlDecode("");
```

[MSDN says Server.HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx) only does the following:

- The less-than character (<) is converted to &lt ;.
- The greater-than character (>) is converted to &gt ;.
- The ampersand character (&) is converted to &amp ;.
- The double-quote character (") is converted to &quot ;.
- Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80 is converted to &#< number>, where number is the ASCII character value.

### Edit 1

But I will suggest you to use `AntiXSS Library`
More detail

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx

Download `.dll` link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28589