# How to remove control chars from UTF8 string

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, utf-8

i have a VB.NET program that handles the content of documents.
The programm handles high volumes of documents as "batch"(>2Million documents;total 1TB volume)
Some of this documents may contain control chars or chars like f0e8(http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f0e8/browsertest.htm).

Is there a easy and especially **fast** way to remove that chars?(except space,newline,tab,...)
If the answer is regex: Has anyone a **complete** regex for me?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem with the control characters? I'm assuming that they are appropriate for the documents themselves.

Comment: The program uses different parsers(word,pdf,...) and deals with plain/text and xml files. Sometimes the (extracted) "body"/content string still contains annoying chars like "f0e8". So I have to remove them myself

Comment: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=61568&number=512 says that f0e8 is a utf8 char or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes the extractor doens't remove all "design" chars.But I can't change it

Comment: For future reference see section "Unicode Character Properties" here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "\p{C}+", "");
```

This will remove all "other" Unicode characters (control, format, private use, surrogate, and unassigned) from your string.

Comment: Thank you very much :D Works well! I hop it won't slow down the process to much.

Comment: Why is the @ not accepted in Visual Basic? I get the "expression expected" error at the @.

Comment: Oops. I had overlooked the VB part, and my knee-jerk reaction to the .NET tag was to provide a C# code snippet. Will edit. Thanks!

Comment: Ist there an overview what chars are removed by "\p{C}+"? Thanks!

Comment: Check out http://www.unicode.org/charts/, scroll down to the bottom and look at the rightmost column.

Comment: See here for a C# version:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568888/430742

Answer (score 0):

Here is the POSIX regex for control characters: `[:cntrl:]`, from [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Posix is quite dead, may it rest in pieces.