# C# regex to remove non - printable characters, and control characters, in a text that has a mix of many different languages, unicode letters

Tags: c#, regex, unicode

i would appreciate your help on this, since i do not know which range of characters to use, or if there is a character class like [[:cntrl:]] that i have found in ruby?

by means of non printable, i mean delete all characters that are not shown in ie output, when one prints the input string. Please note, i look for a c# regex, i do not have a problem with my code

Comment: What characters are supposed to be non-printable? You need to build the regex character class for that. Perhaps, you just want `\p{C}` (= *invisible control characters and unused code points*), or `\p{Cc}` (just control characters, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

Answer (score 102):

You may remove all control and other non-printable characters with

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\p{C}+", string.Empty);
```

The `\p{C}` Unicode category class matches all control characters, even those outside the ASCII table because in .NET, Unicode category classes are Unicode-aware by default.

**Breaking it down into subcategories**

- To only match **basic control characters** you may use `\p{Cc}+`, see 65 chars in the [Other, Control](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cc/list.htm) Unicode category. It is equal to a `[\u0000-\u0008\u000E-\u001F\u007F-\u0084\u0086-\u009F \u0009-\u000D \u0085]+` regex.
- To only match **161 [*other format*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cf/list.htm) chars** including the well-known soft hyphen (`\u00AD`), zero-width space (`\u200B`), zero-width non-joiner (`\u200C`), zero-width joiner (`\u200D`), left-to-right mark (`\u200E`) and right-to-left mark (`\u200F`) use `\p{Cf}+`. The equivalent including astral place code points is a `(?:[\xAD\u0600-\u0605\u061C\u06DD\u070F\u08E2\u180E\u200B-\u200F\u202A-\u202E\u2060-\u2064\u2066-\u206F\uFEFF\uFFF9-\uFFFB]|\uD804[\uDCBD\uDCCD]|\uD80D[\uDC30-\uDC38]|\uD82F[\uDCA0-\uDCA3]|\uD834[\uDD73-\uDD7A]|\uDB40[\uDC01\uDC20-\uDC7F])+` regex.
- To match **137,468 [Other, Private Use control code points](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Co/list.htm)** you may use `\p{Co}+`, or its equivalent including astral place code points, `(?:[\uE000-\uF8FF]|[\uDB80-\uDBBE\uDBC0-\uDBFE][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uDBBF\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFD])+`.
- To match **2,048 [*Other, Surrogate* code points](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Cs/list.htm)** that include some emojis, you may use `\p{Cs}+`, or `[\uD800-\uDFFF]+` regex.

Comment: I up-voted for the interesting approach and Unicode compatibility, though I would argue that tab, carriage-return, line-feed, etc could be interpreted as "printable" in some applications (eg, my own), so I prefer the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14568679/5818981).

Comment: @SteveCinq Then you may also use `@"[\p{C}-[\r\n\t]]+"` and add any other symbol into the nested brackets that you want to avoid replacing.

Comment: Here is the list of **Supported Unicode general categories** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories Tip: Take a look at the **Supported named blocks** (below)

Comment: @Doomjunky That is a good reference, just note that those Unicode category classes do not match Unicode code points, they only match code units, that is why I added hex patterns that include all relevant code points. These code points can be obtained at [Unicode Utilities: UnicodeSet](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp).

Comment: TIL [Astral Plane](https://everything2.com/title/Astral+Plane) unicode.

Answer (score 6):

<s>You can try with :</s>

```
string s = "Täkörgåsmrgås";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", string.Empty);
```

---

Updated answer after comments:

Documentation about non-printable character:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Char.IsControl Method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iscontrol.aspx

Maybe you can try:

```
string input; // this is your input string
string output = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: thank you very much, i will try this, i only needed the regex, i have the code, my fear was not to  loose any printable characters in the way :)

Comment: I think you will, the output is : "Tkrgsmrgs", can you gave an exemple of which characters you wish to remove ?

Comment: then this is not what i want, this is what i was afraid of, loosing characters from the screen. My goal is to remove characters, that are not shown in the screen, but they exist in it, and are useless, to give you an example, in JAVA i can keep all those characters with a  \p{Print}

Comment: This worked for me. My problem was different such I need to support UTF-8 but I also want to strip out the control characters.

Answer (score 2):

To remove all control and other non-printable characters

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\p{C}+", String.Empty);
```

To remove the control characters only (if you don't want to remove the emojis )

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\p{Cc}+", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
    public static string TrimNonAscii(this string value)
    {
        string pattern = "[^ -~]*";
        Regex reg_exp = new Regex(pattern);
        return reg_exp.Replace(value, "");
    }
```