# string.IsNullOrEmpty & string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace return false for empty string

Tags: c#, .net

I have run into a curious case where a block of code that is designed to weed out blank strings, periods dashes and the like after a paragraph of text is processed from the MSFT Azure Phrase Breaker.   I could use help figuring out how to debug the issue.

The following block of code returns `true` when given a value of `""`.   Obviously the expectation is the method should return `false` after the first `if` statement.  Out of 899 phrases to be looked at, only two seem to have this problem.   Happens on another machine as well.

```
public static bool IsSentenceTranslatable(string sentence)
{
    string trimmedSentence = sentence.Trim();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmedSentence) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trimmedSentence))
    {
        return false;
    }

    switch (trimmedSentence)
    {
        case " ":
        case ".":
        case "-":
        case "·":
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the debugger.

[image: Debugger Snapshot]

Could it be a bug in Visual Studio or .NET?   I tried using the various visualizers, but still couldn't see anything in the box.  .NET 4.5 C# 7.3

Comment: Maybe a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)?

Comment: Doesn't that `trimmedSentence.Length` having a value of 1 pretty much tell you already that the string is -indeed- non empty? Have you tried checking the value of `trimmedSentence[0]`?

Comment: BTW: In 120% of all cases where I assumed something to be a "…bug in Visual Studio or .NET…", it turned out it was my fault.

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564692/c-sharp-regex-to-remove-non-printable-characters-and-control-characters-in-a/40568888). Your string has invisible characters after you copied the text from example a website.

Comment: Text came from XLF file.

Comment: @Andrew the spirit of my question was how to debug it and `trimmedSentence[0]` did the trick to unlocking the right google search.    If you submit an answer ill mark it as approved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, in that screenshot you can see that `trimmedSentence.Length` is 1, therefore it's not empty, and its contents is definitely not a standard space. If the string appears empty, it's because it has one of those so-called invisible characters. To check what your string has, you can directly access that character by doing `trimmedSentence[0]`.

If that character will appear often, you might want to consider doing this:

```
string trimmedSentence = sentence.Trim().Replace("<this special character>", "");
```

Alternatively, you can create that replaceable string from the Unicode value by doing `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(yourCharCode).ToString()`. You cannot use the `Replace` overload that uses character parameters, as there is no "empty" character, only an empty string. You should be able to get this value while debugging. Or if necessary, by doing `(int)trimmedSentence[0]`.

Comment: FWIW - when you inspect the first char in the string (ie `trimmedSentence[0]` it might look like a random number with a quote.   Google the number sans quote and you'll get the ascii code.

Comment: BTW, what value was it? As often they are displayed in hexadecimal, you can do `((int)trimmedSentence[0]).ToString("X")` to get the hex representation of this invisible space.

Answer (score 9):

Try to get the string's byte representation. I suspect that it actually contains some character which is invisible in VS debugger but doesn't count as a whitespace.

See this questions for hints:

- [Invisible characters - ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978720/invisible-characters-ascii)
- [Converting string to byte array in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072709/converting-string-to-byte-array-in-c-sharp)

UPD: since your Watch window shows that after the call `string trimmedSentence = sentence.Trim()` you have `trimmedSentence.Length == 1`, I'd upgrade my suspicion to certainty.

Comment: I appreciate this answer but it only tells you what you already know. See the accepted answer which tells you how to actually figure out your next step.

Comment: @TaylorAckley if you already knew this, why did you ask "Could it be a bug in Visual Studio or .NET"?

Comment: I figured there must be something in there, but why do I have to do some manipulation on the string in order to see something?    Seems like one of the visualizers should show something, especially if it has an entity code and you look at it in the HTML visualizer.   Perhaps not a bug, but would be helpful for them to show you something other than empty quotemarks and a blank visualizer.