# Removing non-ASCII characters from string

Tags: c#, string, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to strip non-ASCII character from strings I am reading from a text file and can't get it to do so. I checked some of the suggestions from posts in SO and other sites, all to no avail.

This is what I have and what I have tried:

String in text file:

```
2021-03-26 10:00:16:648|2021-03-26 10:00:14:682|MPE->IDC|[10.20.30.40:41148]|203, ?  ?'F?~?^?W?|?8wL?i??{?=kb ?   Y  R?
```

String read from the file:

```
"2021-03-26 10:00:16:648|2021-03-26 10:00:14:682|[10.20.30.40:41148]|203,\u0016\u0003\u0001\0?\u0001\0\0?\u0003\u0001'F?\u001e~\u0018?^?W\u0013?|?8wL\v?i??{?=kb\t?\tY\u0005\0\0R?"
```

Methods to get rid of non-ASCII characters:

```
Regex reAsciiPattern = new Regex(@"[^\u0000-\u007F]+");  // Non-ASCII characters
sLine = reAsciiPattern.Replace(sLine, "");   // remove non-ASCII chars

Regex reAsciiPattern2 = new Regex(@"[^\x00-\x7F]+");  // Non-ASCII characters
sLine = reAsciiPattern2.Replace(sLine, "");   // remove non-ASCII chars

string asAscii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
    Encoding.Convert(
        Encoding.UTF8,
        Encoding.GetEncoding(
            Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName,
            new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty),
            new DecoderExceptionFallback()
            ),
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sLine)
    )
);
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're confusing ASCII with 'printable'. The characters you have are ascii, just not printable.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without a `Regex` using a loop and a `StringBuilder`:

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var ch in line) {
   //printable Ascii range
   if (ch >= 32 && ch < 127) { 
       sb.Append(ch);
   } 
}

line = sb.ToString();
```

Or you can use some LINQ:

```cs
line = string.Concat(
  line.Where(ch => ch >= 32 && ch < 127)
);
```

If you must do this with Regex then the following should suffice (again this keeps printable ASCII only)

```cs
line = Regex.Replace(line, @"[^\u0020-\u007e]", "");
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##lVFLa8JAEL7vrxj2IBE0JvHQFqvUlt48VaGHPmATx2Rhu0l3N61F8tvT2Si2QqGYw2bY7zHfzGZ2mFnZtrWVOofll3X4Fi6kfp@wk6sVbl34gHmthLnfVgatlaW2E8Y@hAElNcIUeKqe6yi6jPwZXwn/u8CCH1g2JY7GT1g6Q9a3tVRrNEF/wjalQZEVgWdlBUjdOfZhxwBgNKqI7kSqEOY2kxKM0Dl6SG4gIP5sCuMEej2vvYY4uSAleNx/Ng3nVYV6TUxqRTcNsKYLRFPUysWUikirch/L5/mFJh7tgPCu1JlwAVn4dOFjgQZ9@@kM/gzBTp3G5EQbxC3tsVIiw8DbDOCGP736TSXRcL@wFz7g3GupoS0VdTLSIT0KBnwXNTCcwS5u@AD2@i7MAnXu/Hz/aQ4zH4tzlcmxOFc5PhY/Sta23w)

If you want all ASCII (including non-printable) characters, then modify the tests to

```
ch <= 127 // for the loops
@"[^\u0000-\u007f]" // for the regex
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regular expression to get rid of all non-printable characters.

```
Regex.Replace(sLine, @"[^\u0020-\u007E]+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Wouldn't these be covered by the first regular expression I had listed?

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I believe as Poul Bak had commented, I had confused non-ascii with non-printable. In the end I found the solution at anothe SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564692/c-sharp-regex-to-remove-non-printable-characters-and-control-characters-in-a/40568888). I posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me based on a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564692/c-sharp-regex-to-remove-non-printable-characters-and-control-characters-in-a/40568888)

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

Regex reAsciiNonPrintable = new Regex(@"\p{C}+");  // Non-printable characters
string sLine;

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Folder, FileName)))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        sLine = sr.ReadLine().Trim();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLine))
        {
            Match match = reAsciiNonPrintable.Match(sLine);

            if (match.Success)
                continue;    // skip the line
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>` where each `char` represents one UTF-16 code unit (possibly a surrogate), you can also do:

```
var ascii = new string(sLine.Where(x => x <= sbyte.MaxValue).ToArray());
```

Or if you want only printable ASCII:

```
var asciiPrintable = new string(sLine.Where(x => ' ' <= x && x <= '~').ToArray());
```

I realize now that this is mostly a duplicate of pinkfloydx33's answer, so go and upvote that.

If the string contains accented letters, the result can depend on the normalization, so compare:

```
var sLine1 = "olé";
var sLine2 = sLine1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
```