# Escape C# string to HTML

Tags: c#, html, escaping

I have a string with special characters like this:

> äöüß&

Now I want to put that in an HTML document and need to escape these characters. Is there an elegant way doing this?

I could do this:

```
string html;
html = html.Replace("ü", "uu&uml;");
html = html.Replace("ß", "&szlig;");
....
```

But I don't want to do that for all possible special characters.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let the Framework do the work for you.

You could try [`HtmlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx):

```
string encodedHtml = Server.HtmlEncode(html);
```

Comment: @juergend - Check the documentation I linked to. Has the namespace and the assembly (in case you need to add a reference).

Comment: I didn't see that at first. Actually even after using the `System.Web` namespace and referencing the System.Web.dll in my Project, VS2010 still can't find the Server class. But it finds this which works perfectly: `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`

Answer (score 10):

There is also this, intended for XML, but it should work just fine with HTML:

`System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape( string s );`

Comment: See extended notes (corroborating you) @ http://stackoverflow.com/a/1934252/41153

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting into the habit of using [Microsoft's AntiXSS Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx), and calling

```
AntiXSS.HtmlEncode(yourstring);
```

if you need to include it in the body, or

```
AntiXSS.HtmlAttributeEncode(yourstring);
```

if it is going inside an HTML attribute.

Comment: This library is obselete and is replaced by Encoder.HtmlEncode().