# How to show `&` followed by a word `param` in an asp label in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

It is interesting that the asp:Label in ItemTemplate converts the following value `userId=%UserId%&param=%param%` into `userId=%UserId%¶m=%param%`. It converts `&para` into `¶`.

The aspx code looks something like this, it uses `asp:ObjectDataSource` to get the data to bind:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvLink" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsLink" AutoGenerateRows="False" DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="LinkId" OnModeChanged="dvLink_ModeChanged">
   <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parameters" SortExpression="Parameters">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblParameters" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Parameters") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbParameters" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Parameters") %>' Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbParameters" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Parameters") %>' Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dsLink" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetLink"
    TypeName="LinkLib" InsertMethod="SaveLink"
    OnInserted="dsLink_Inserted" OnUpdated="dsLink_Updated"
    UpdateMethod="SaveLink" DataObjectTypeName="LinkLib">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gvLinks" Name="LinkId" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
            Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="auth" Type="Object" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

How can I escape `&para` during bind so it doesn't convert it into html code?

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code segment that shows the value and how it gets assigned to the label., so we can see the "before" and "after".

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306053/escape-html-entities-and-avoid-html-injection-in-webform-label

Comment: you can have apostrophe show if you you use &apos;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape HTML-entities and avoid HTML-injection in WebForm Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306053/escape-html-entities-and-avoid-html-injection-in-webform-label)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Greg for pointing out to a right SO article, that solved the issue. Here is the solution, if someone has a similar issue:

I changed `<asp:label>` to `<asp:Literal>` to fix the issue. Also, make sure to use the following attribute `Mode="Encode"`.

I replaced this aspx code

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblParameters" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Parameters") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

to

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="lblParameters" runat="server" Mode="Encode" Text='<%# Bind("Parameters") %>'></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate>
```