# Write in an XML document with C# using special characters

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to write an XML file in C# using **XmlWriter** in a recursive function. The file is supposed to contain every single folder in a given directory as well as every subfolder and file.

I'm having some trouble in trying to write special characters in the XML file, it's constantly giving me the error that

> I can't use characters such as '&', '/', '-', '.', ' ' etc.

And even numbers aren't working. I have tried finding similar questions to this problem and no solution helped me, I have tried replacing the folder and/or file string name that consists of special characters and escaping them using "&amp ;", "&quot ;", "&apos ;" etc. But that isn't working either. It just gives me an error that I can't use '&'.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace XMLgenerator
{
    public class Generator
    {
        public void write(string Dir, XmlWriter writer)
        {
            try
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Folders");
                 foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir))
              {
                    string[] splitter = s.Split('\\');
                    string ss = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
                    string ssxml = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(ss);
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", ssxml);

                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(s))
                    {
                        string fxml = XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(f);
                        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(f);
                        long length =  fi.Length;
                        writer.WriteElementString(fxml, length.ToString());
                    }
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    write(s,writer);
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
        // Method for creating an XML file and also getting directories and files. File name and dir path are parametres
        public void generateContent(string Dir)
            {
            XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xws.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", xws))
            {
                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                write(Dir,writer);
                writer.WriteEndDocument();
            }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The space before the `;` is making the escaped character invalid.  `&amp;` is '&' while `&amp ;` is '&amp ;'  There's also [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005264/escape-text-for-html) so you don't need to code for every possible invalid character.

Comment: Hey Paul, I just made that space in this question because without it it translates it properly here, so instead of &amp it gives the actual &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to include '&', '/', '-', '.', ' ' and whatnot in an *XML element name*.  Some of these such as '&' cannot be included in an element name at all while others such as '-' and digits can be included -- just not as the first character.  The [XML Standard 4th edition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-common-syn) (which is the version [currently supported by `XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)) defines the valid characters in a name as follows:

```
[4]     NameChar    ::=     Letter | Digit | '.' | '-' | '_' | ':' | CombiningChar | Extender
[5]     Name        ::=     (Letter | '_' | ':') (NameChar)*
```

Where `Letter`, `Digit` et. al. are defined [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#NT-Letter).  Note that a letter must be first.

Since your `ss` string might include invalid characters, you can use [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname(v=vs.110).aspx) to escape as required, then later use [`XmlConvert.DecodeName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.decodename(v=vs.110).aspx) to recover the original string when reading the XML.

Thus, your code would look something like:

```
    public void write(string Dir, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folders");
            foreach (string directoryPath in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir))
            {
                string directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath);
                writer.WriteStartElement(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(directoryName));
                foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    writer.WriteElementString(XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName(fileName), XmlConvert.ToString(fi.Length));
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                write(directoryPath, writer);
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
```

However, I would suggest an alternate approach of using fixed element names, as recommended by @PaulAbbott, which stores directory and file names as attribute values:

```
    public void write(string Dir, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folders");
            foreach (string directoryPath in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir))
            {
                string directoryName = Path.GetFileName(directoryPath);
                writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", directoryName);
                foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath))
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", fileName);
                    writer.WriteValue(fi.Length);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
                write(directoryPath, writer); // I moved this inside the outer <Folder> tag.
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
```

This should produce more readable XML, such as:

```
<Folders>
  <Folder Name="WpfApplication1">
    <File Name="D:\Temp\Question27864746 XMLapp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1.sln">1014</File>
    <File Name="D:\Temp\Question27864746 XMLapp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1.v12.suo">84992</File>
    <Folders>
      <Folder Name="WpfApplication1">
        <File Name="D:\Temp\Question27864746 XMLapp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\App.config">187</File>
        <File Name="D:\Temp\Question27864746 XMLapp\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\App.xaml">326</File>
      </Folder>
    </Folders>
  </Folder>
</Folders>
```

Comment: I didn't even realize he was creating *element names* out of folder names.    This is a really bad idea because there is no possible way you could write an XSD for it.  Something like `<folders><folder name="asdf">...` would be a lot better than `<folders><asdf>...` and avoid issues like folder names starting with numbers.

Comment: @PaulAbbott - agreed.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much guys,I took both of your tips and everything is alright. Can I just ask you how to make the elements and element strings formed like a tree?

Comment: @LukaZdravkovic - did my update answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to fix your xml, use Linq2Xml to achive the similar thing.

I would do it as (no string manuplation, no special char handling)

```
XElement Dir2Xml(string dir)
{
    var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
    var files = new XElement("files");

    foreach(var f in dInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        files.Add(new XElement("file", f.FullName)); //or use "f.Name" whichever you like
    }

    foreach (var d in dInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        files.Add(new XElement("directory", new XAttribute("name", d.Name), Dir2Xml(d.FullName)));
    }

    return files;
}
```

---

```
var xmlstring = Dir2Xml(@"c:\temp").ToString();
```