# C# - Javascript escape() alternative for every character?

Tags: javascript, c#

I need an example to encode: `abcdef` into: `%61%62%63%64%65%66`.

The only way I found of doing this is on this website: http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/encode-decode.html

But how can I do this in C# manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape text for HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005264/escape-text-for-html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Encoding using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp)

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp) post, take a look at the hex escaped encoding.

Comment: Its not a duplicate, all those methods dont encode ASCII chars.

Comment: @ventiseis that doesnt solve as it doesnt encode ABCD etc

Comment: Look at the column `HexEscaped` in the large overview table -- first line reads `A  %41`. Why isn't this working for you?

Comment: @ventiseis My bad! Didn't see that, is it possible, to use Uri.HexEscape on a string rather than 1 character at a time?

Comment: @user7838393 Didn't find anything, but it's not that hard to implement..

Answer (score 0):

```
string TextToEncode= "abcdef";
var encodedText = "%" + string.Join("%", from c in TextToEncode select ((int)c).ToString("X"));

//encodedText  = %61%62%63%64%65%66
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/433015618/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply.