# How do I get XML or HTML results to display preformatted in FitNesse?

Tags: formatting, fitnesse

In FitNesse's own acceptance tests, many times we can see output in the form of HTML being displayed when a test is run. Typically the output is wrapped in `<pre>..</pre>` and is displayed with a blue background. The wiki markup isn't anything special, just an empty cell in a column fixture (it seems) which displays the output, e.g.

`|Response Requester.|
 |uri|valid?|contents?|
 |!-VariablePage-!|true||`

(This is from the test FitNesse.SuiteAcceptanceTests.SuiteWidgetTests.TestVariables)

The contents column displays nicely preformatted HTML output on a blue background when the test is run.

How is this achieved?

Comment: Looking at that fixture, it says `return "<pre>" + HtmlUtil.escapeHTML(FitnesseFixtureContext.sender.sentData()) + "</pre>";`.

Comment: @legoscia I suspect this is in the Java fixture code, right? I'm using .Net and there's no HtmlUtil class. Does anyone know if there's an alternative?

Comment: You'd need to escape special HTML characters to their corresponding HTML entities. There are a few suggestions in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1005264/113848

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, but the example from FitNesse's own acceptance tests is not HTML escaped, it's just inside a <pre>...</pre>. So how does FitNesse get that cell to have a blue background? The text is in a span with CSS class "ignore". There's more going on here, no? Somehow the cell is given special treatment.

Comment: The blue background suggests that there was no assertion for this value; Fitnesse is just "reporting" it without this being either a "green" or "red" value. In Slim, that happens automatically in decision tables when there is no assertion. Is this using Slim or Fit? Fit might do this differently...

Comment: @legoscia ah that could be it. I'm using Fit and it doesn't show these "informational" cells in a different colour.