# How to convert html to text without removing html tags

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, html-parsing

[convert this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZbiZ.png) [into this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKL2t.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKL2t.png)
I am trying to convert the text with html tags(p,ol, b)  [!
into normal text(like the result of run code snippet) - I have tried with the below code in .net core but the result is plain html without formatting(eg: p tag should show paragraph, <ol should convert to numbers, <b should make the text bold etc..)

```
 var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sampleHtml);
            var innertext = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

also tried with HTMLAgility pack, but no luck.

```
Html.Raw(sampleHtml) works with mvc razor but not with .net core.
```

```html
<p>Angular is a platform for building mobile and desktop web applications. It has a big community of millions of developers who choose Angular to build compelling user interfaces.:</p><ol><li>Angular is a JavaScript open-source front-end web application framework..</li><li>Angular solves many of the challenges faced when developing single page, cross platform, performant applications.</li></ol><p><b>Angular</b/></p><p><b>What's new</b/></p><p><b>Angular is a complete rewrite of AngularJS.</b/></p><p>Angular does not have a "scope" concept or controllers, instead, it uses a component hierarchy as its main architecture.</p><p><b>Warning</b/></p><p>Static Typing (<b>support</b>) for the purpose of study.
```

Kindly comment your ideas and ways to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. For me "convert text to html" means, you have a string with e.g. line breaks and want a string with <p> tags as result. I think that's not what you mean? Also I don't know what "plain html without formatting" is. HTML per definition means "with html tags formatted text" - so a string can be html formatted or not, but what is an html formatted string without formatting?

Comment: Try using `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`

Comment: @Christoph Lütjen I have added the image screenshots for clarity. Conversion can be in .net core or angular 2+. Thanks

Comment: @Sara Stoimenovska  innerHTML also did not get the desired results. Thanks

Comment: the html text containing (p,ol,b) is rendered by the browser to paragraph, numbers, bold. Where/how do you want to display this text?

Comment: reading that text from database column using .net core and displaying in browser using angular material

Comment: Sounds like you want to escape html special characters? You can do so in c# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005264/escape-text-for-html or angular or JavaScript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities - i'd do it in JavaScript following because it's view related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your responses. I was able to do it in angular template instead of getting the converted html from C# using `<p [innerHTML]="sampleHtml">'. innerHTML></p>`, innerHTML does not work with 'textarea' which I was trying to do, so I used a paragraph, div can also be used.